# Increasing or decreasing sample size with higher correlation among repeated measures in G*Power

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size, statistical-power

When I conduct an a priori power analysis to calculate the required sample size with G* power for a repeated measures design with between factors, the sample size increases when I insert a higher value for correlations among repeated measures.

However, when I choose the 'repeated measures, within-between interactions' variant, the opposite is true: the sample size decreases as a result of a higher correlation among repeated measures value.

What am I not understandig here? For me, it would be logical that with a higher test-retest reliability, you would need fewer participants than with a lower reliability, in general.

We will do a study with one within subjects variable (time: pretest vs. posttest) and one between subjects variable (condition: training vs. control). So, we are interested in the interaction between time and condition, therefore I assume we want to choose the within-between interaction option in G*power, but I am getting slightly confused here.

I hope you can help.

With kind regards,
Johanna

Comment: Anyone who can help?